# Use only the custom dictionary for spell checking in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check, language-pack

I would like to make MS Word use only the custom dictionary to spell check the Chechen language as it doesn't have any official spell check package available.

Is there any way to turn off the main dictionary while not turning off the spell checking system itself?

If that's not possible, please share your ideas on what is the best thing for me to do to achieve the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any setting for using only the custom dictionary,
although there is a setting for using *only the main dictionary*.
You may then need to replace the main dictionary itself.

The main dictionary is located in the file
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Spelling\LANGUAGE\default.dic`.

You may replace the file `default.dic` by your `.dic` file.
If this works, keep always a backup of the file if you add any words,
in case that some future update to Office may replace it.
Remember also that there is a separate file for each installed language.